# Cannot get wifi to work

Tags: networking, wireless, rfkill

Please help trying to get wifi working on my laptop with new ubuntu
info is below

```
anita@anita-Presario-CQ57-Notebook-PC:~$ rfkill list
0: hp-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
anita@anita-Presario-CQ57-Notebook-PC:~$ lspci -vnn | grep Network
07:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. RT5390 Wireless 802.11n T/1R PCIe [1814:5390]
```

Comment: Did a software update and the wifi is now showing as below

Comment: 0: hp-wifi: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: yes
 Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: yes

Comment: Turn on the wifi by pressing the physical button for wifi on your laptop..I think it should work. or try `rfkill unblock all`

Comment: Hi Ron,
Thanks for the suggestion, I turned the wifi on with the button and ran a 'nmcli nm' and it showed wifi hardware was enabled but wifi itself was still disabled?

Comment: how about running `rfkill unblock all`?

Comment: I tried this last night and it didn't allow it for some reason (cant remember the message that came up), I'll give it another go at lunch time today. thanks

Comment: Hi Ron, Nope still no joy. Nothing happens when i run rfkill unblock all, when i run nmcli nm the Wifi is still showing as disabled even though the wifi hardware is enabled